# Passing Context From Service Class to another Service Class

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to pass Context from my service to other Service but its showing error that

error: incompatible types: PushListenerService cannot be converted to Context

Here is my PushListenerService

```
public class PushListenerService extends QBFcmPushListenerService {
private static final String TAG = PushListenerService.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    SharedPrefsHelper sharedPrefsHelper = SharedPrefsHelper.getInstance();
    if (sharedPrefsHelper.hasQbUser()) {
        QBUser qbUser = sharedPrefsHelper.getQbUser();
        Log.d(TAG, "App has logged user" + qbUser.getId());
        LoginService.start(this, qbUser); //this is the error not getting this as Context
    }
}

@Override
protected void sendPushMessage(Map data, String from, String message) {
    super.sendPushMessage(data, from, message);
    Log.v(TAG, "From: " + from);
    Log.v(TAG, "Message: " + message);
}
```

}

here is my LoginService.start start Method where I'm passing the Context

```
 public class LoginService extends Service {

 public static void start(Context context, QBUser qbUser) {
        start(context, qbUser, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The java keyword `this` referes to the current object hence it's a reference variable to an instance of the `PushListenerService` class while the `LoginService` seems to take an object of type `Context`. If this is in a Spring context try passing an autowired applicatoin context.

```
public class PushListenerService extends QBFcmPushListenerService {
  private static final String TAG = PushListenerService.class.getSimpleName();

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext context;

  @Override
  public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
   super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
   SharedPrefsHelper sharedPrefsHelper = SharedPrefsHelper.getInstance();
   if (sharedPrefsHelper.hasQbUser()) {
    QBUser qbUser = sharedPrefsHelper.getQbUser();
    Log.d(TAG, "App has logged user" + qbUser.getId());
    LoginService.start(context, qbUser);
   }
 }
```